# Display Video by value of page item in Apex23.1

Tags: oracle-apex

for displaying videos in Apex23.1 , I use this [plugin](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::::P710_PLG_ID:DE.DANIELH.VIDEOPLAYER).

But I want to refresh and show videos by clicking on each row of interactive grid individually .

this plugin can't make effort for what I need .
Is there any options or plugins that could help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need a plugin at all. You could use a region of type dynamic content. In that region, use native [HTML Video element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

It allows you to use the "source" attribute of the HTML element from your SQL logic and you don't depend on some plugins.

You may also need to adjust the styling of your region as you wish.

[Here](https://blog.cloudnueva.com/apex-222-dynamic-content-regions) is also a good tutorial of how to use dynamic content regions in case you are not familiar with it.

Comment: thanks a lot that works ! Do you know how could I make a autoplay video based on order of report records ?

Comment: Check autoplay attribute of HTML Video tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp